# Extract unused react components in an enterprise solution

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am working in a `monorepo` which has been in development for a few years. The codebase is big and it is very hard to find components which are no longer in use. I did analyze the codebase with `webpack bundle analyzer`, but the report is not that helpful. We are trying to move them in a folder called `deprecated`. We tried to move unused react components manually, as much as possible but the process is very time consuming and fragile.

I am wondering is there any other tool or techniques that make finding these unused react components easy.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: which tool/framework used for monorepo?

Comment: If you use webpack, you could try, 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-deadcode-plugin

Comment: @Vaibhav nothing special. just a webpack config for different environments.

Comment: @ViniciusKatata we are usegin webpack 5, which I guess that npm package does not support it at the moment

Answer (score 0):

there is a npm package called "react-unused-components" it can help
link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-unused-components

or you can take look into following repo

git : https://github.com/CVarisco/delete-react-zombies

reddit link : https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/7z6bo0/cli_to_search_and_delete_unused_components_in/

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-unused-components
it is an empty repository

Comment: Looks like it is an empty repository